# Snapshot Data is Null and Keeps Loading

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

The snapshot is null and keeps giving an endless circular progress indicator, instead of loading posts. I'm trying to get it to load the posts onto the page, adding it to the database works but seeing the posts on the screen just gives a endlessloading state. Here is the code:

```
    Widget feed = FutureBuilder(
      future: _getFeedFuture,
      builder: (BuildContext ctx, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting ||
            snapshot.data == null) {
          return Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              CircularProgressIndicator(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 16.0,
              ),
              Text('Loading ....'),
            ],
          );
        } else if (snapshot.data.length == 0) {
          return Text('No data to display');
        } else {
          return Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: _posts,
          );
        }
      },
    );

    _items.add(feed);

    return _items;
  }
```

The getFuturefeed is equal to the get Feed below.

```
  Future _getFeed() async {
    _posts = [];

    Query _query = _firestore
        .collection('posts')
        .orderBy('created', descending: true)
        .limit(10);
    QuerySnapshot _quertSnapshot = await _query.getDocuments();

    _postDocuments = _quertSnapshot.documents;
    _lastDocument = _postDocuments[_postDocuments.length - 1];

    for (var i = 0; i < _postDocuments.length; ++i) {
      Widget w = _makeCard(_postDocuments[i]);

      _posts.add(w);
    }

    return _postDocuments;
  }
```

Comment: So I would suggest putting a couple of print statements above the `if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting ||
            snapshot.data == null) {` to see what connection state and snapshot.data are. Also, your getFeed method seems to assume it will always get what it expects. You need to consider possible errors there as well.

Comment: @GrahamD the snapshot.data printed as null.

Comment: So while your snapshot is null, you will always see the spinner. There is something wrong with your data query, it is not returning anything. You need to handle that gracefully and not show an endless spinner.

Comment: This is happening in my device but working fine in emulator.